# How can i get control over the Music lights in Sony walkman?

Tags: android, notifications, media-player, sony

I am planning to write code so that i can use the Music light at the top of my phone as the notification light. I would like to know how can i get the hardware id or control over the Music light.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think sony erricson has opened api for these lights. I suggest you to check it on http://developer.sonymobile.com/. Search with your mobile Device type & android verison.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Sony Mobile has published experimental API
http://developer.sonymobile.com/2013/06/20/new-experimental-illumination-bar-api-available/